# Удаление строки из таблицы SQL через веб-форму ASP

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

Вот такой код

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="PrinterSource">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <table id="example" class="table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Имя</th>
                        <th>IP</th>
                        <th>Этаж</th>
                        <th>Кабинет</th>
                        <th>Статус</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <%# Eval("printername")%>

      </td>
                <td>
                    <%# Eval("ip")%>

      </td>
                <td>
                    <%# Eval("floor")%>

      </td>
                <td>
                    <%# Eval("cab")%>

      </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="DeletePrinter" runat="server" Text="Button" CssClass="btn btn-primary" OnClick="DeletePrinter_Click" />

                </td>
            </tr>

        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </table>

        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Я добавил, в каждую строчку кнопку удаления

```
  <asp:Button ID="DeletePrinter" runat="server" Text="Button" CssClass="btn btn-primary" OnClick="DeletePrinter_Click" />
```

И тут у меня возник тупик, что мне передать событию онклик, чтобы произошло удаление записи. Как я понимаю, мне нужно получить ID записи от клиента, а потом коннектиться к базе и удалять эту запись. Как это сделать ? Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблему можно решить через CommandArgument в asp:Button

```
<asp:Button ID="DeletePrinter" 
        runat="server" 
        Text="Button" 
        CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID")%>"'
        CssClass="btn btn-primary" 
        OnCommand="DeletePrinter_Click" />
```

Когда пользователь нажмет на кнопку удалить, в обработчик предаст аргумент текущий кнопки

Вот еще ссылка на msdn https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.commandargument(v=vs.110).aspx